# How to determinate if my application is running under SYSTEM account or not?

Tags: c++, windows

How could I decide if my application is running under LocalSystem Account or not? Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Err, try something that only the system account can do? Let the system tell you after you try whatever it is that you want to do: don't decide ahead of time. This strategy applies to many operations in computing, for example detecting resource availability,

Comment: @EJP The suggestion usually applies, but not always. Consider a UI that displays different options when running under a particular account.

Comment: A common hack used to be trying to open a handle on `lsass.exe` or the process, or something similar. This either succeeds or fails (depending on whether you're "system" or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I might have found a way. Not the best, I know, but it works.

```
BOOL CheckIfRunningAsSYSTEM( VOID )  
{
DWORD i, dwSize = 0, dwResult = 0;
HANDLE hToken;
PTOKEN_USER Ptoken_User;

// Open a handle to the access token for the calling process.
if ( !OpenProcessToken( GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken ) )
{
    printf( "OpenProcessToken Error %u\n", GetLastError() );
    return FALSE;
}

// Call GetTokenInformation to get the buffer size.
if ( !GetTokenInformation( hToken, TokenUser, NULL, dwSize, &dwSize ) )
{
    dwResult = GetLastError();
    if ( dwResult != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER )
    {
        printf( "GetTokenInformation Error %u\n", dwResult );
        return FALSE;
    }
}

// Allocate the buffer.
Ptoken_User = ( PTOKEN_USER )GlobalAlloc( GPTR, dwSize );

// Call GetTokenInformation again to get the group information.
if ( !GetTokenInformation( hToken, TokenUser, Ptoken_User, dwSize, &dwSize ) )
{
    printf( "GetTokenInformation Error %u\n", GetLastError() );
    return FALSE;
}

LPWSTR SID = NULL;

if ( !ConvertSidToStringSidW( Ptoken_User->User.Sid, &SID ) )
{
    printf( "\nConvertSidToStringSidW failed. Error = %d", GetLastError() );
    return FALSE;
}
else printf( "\nConvertSidToStringSidW succeeded." );

if ( _wcsicmp( L"S-1-5-18", SID ) == 0 ) printf( "\nRunning under SYSTEM" );
else printf( "\nNOT running under SYSTEM" );

if ( Ptoken_User ) GlobalFree( Ptoken_User );

return TRUE;

}//CheckIfRunningAsSYSTEM
```

Comment: May I be so inquisitive to ask what's bad, as in *"not the best"*, with this solution? Of course you could [Search for a SID in an Access Token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379554.aspx) instead, but there's really not much difference.

Comment: @IInspectable: Actually you are right. There would be not much difference, but I thought, there may be another ways to do it. This one was the first one, I thought it could be working.

Comment: +1.  The `ConvertSidToStringSid` function is a bit more heavyweight than strictly necessary, but unless you're going to call this function a thousand times a second it isn't worth the effort it would take to remove it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I want to call this function only one time. I only know this way, to convert a SID, to a string, but if you have any other idea i'm open to it.

Comment: I would have used `CreateWellKnownSid` to build a SID for `SYSTEM` and then `EqualSid` to check whether it matched the one in the token.

Comment: You should do CloseHandle on hToken before leaving your function